# How to bind a model to resource store method in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, binding, model, routes

I am trying to assign a Product model for store route which is made by `Route::resource` method

```
public function store(Request $request, Product $product)
```

I already worked with Route Model Binding a little, and it works very nice with

```
public function show(Product $product)
```

But I can't force a `store` method to use `Product` model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since somebody marked this question as favourite I will explain what I did to make it work

This is how we declare our routes, we need to place out specific route before `Route::resource` call

```
Route::post('foo/{baz}', [
        'as'    => 'foo.store',
        'uses'  => 'FooController@store']
);
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
```

Our `Foo` controller store method:

```
public function store(Baz $baz, Request $request){

}
```

The `$baz` variable is just passed after url slash in form action url. it can be like that

```
<form action="foo/5">
```

Keep in mind that `"foo&baz=5"` won't work

For some reason I didn't have to, or at least didn't try to bind a `Foo` model with controller - it just works.

The order of routes and parameters in controller method if important for PHP reflection